# Why is Chrome not showing any data for my User Timing API usage?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome

Chrome's dev tools are not logging anything coming from my usage of the User Timing API. I'm using Chrome 68. I can see it working with other sites that use it, but my code shows nothing. There are no errors.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            performance.mark('Test');
            for (let j = 0; j < 500; j++) {
                Math.cbrt(Math.random() * 1000);
                console.log(j);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It think that you need to give it a start and end tag then measure , something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        performance.mark('start');

        for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < 500; j++) {
                Math.cbrt(Math.random() * 1000);
                console.log(j);
            }         

        }
            performance.mark('end');
            performance.measure('My Benchmark', 'start', 'end');

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```